# How to try catch async/ await functions in a proper way?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I try to understand behavior of try catch'ing async/ await function.
Taking an example and invoking function:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const res = await new Promise(res => {setTimeout(() => res({a: 1}), 2000)});    
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
    }
    console.log(res['a']);
})();
```

It results in error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: res is not defined
at <anonymous>:7:14
```

How the code should be written if I do await assignment in a try block and I want make a further line use of the promise value?

Comment: If the `catch` block is entered, the assignment has failed - further use of the value, if it may not exist, should probably be in the `try` block (call a function with the value as a parameter?)

Comment: Okay, but when the `try` block assigne the value after two second, where should be the `console.log(res['a'])`? And, for example, if the succesfully returned value from first `await` assignment would be then used within another `await` assignment should it be placed withing another `try-catch` block inside the first `try-catch` block?

Comment: See the duplicate. `const` is scoped to the `try` *block*.

Comment: Just put it all in the `try`: `const res = await...; const somethingElse = await <something with res>`

Comment: Okay. I think I understand it now. Thank you.